# VBA while-looping with for/if conditions

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on this macro to extract the relavant information from an excel sheet to a new one. But i just can't seem to get it to work and it's making me crazy.

Can you find the error or suggest a better approch?

EDIT: I want to sort through the data in a sheets column c and if it matches my critera (if) i want to match it to the Group (fruit/berry) and also get data from adjecent columns (P,I,R) and take this whole extraxt and add it to a new sheet (ws2)

```
Private Sub Extract_Click()

Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim i,k as Integer

set ws1 = Workbook.Activesheet

Set ws2 = Worksheets.Add(After:= _
      Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)) 
ws2.Name = "Extract" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count 

With ws1

i = 10
k = 2  

    Do While Not Range("C" & i).Value = ""

            If Range("C" & i).Value = "Strawberry" Then

                ws1.Range("C" & i).Copy
                ws2.Range("A" & k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                ws2.Range("B" & k).Value = "Berry"

                ws1.Range("P" & i).Copy
                ws2.Range("C" & k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                ws1.Range("I" & i).Copy
                ws2.Range("D" & k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                ws1.Range("R" & i).Copy
                ws2.Range("E" & k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

            ElseIf Range("C" & i).Value = "banana" Then

                ws1.Range("C" & i).Copy
                ws2.Range("A" & k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                ws2.Range("B" & k).Value = "Fruit"

                ws1.Range("P" & i).Copy
                ws2.Range("C" & k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                ws1.Range("I" & i).Copy
                ws2.Range("D" & k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                ws1.Range("R" & i).Copy
                ws2.Range("E" & k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

            End If

       k = k+1
   i = i +1 

Loop 

End With


End Sub
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do?

Comment: don't copy and paste, just use the values, ws2.range("a1").value=ws.range("a1").value, turn calculation to manual, and yes, what's the desired output?  Also ws1, wont be defined the same as ws2 only the last one takes the type, you need to define each one.  You also don't set ws1 to anything

Comment: @Nathan_Sav  I liked the idea of copy/pasting but i tried with your approch  ws2.Range("A" & k) = ws1.Range("C" & i).Value and it work just fine - thank you very much

Comment: No probs, but you're essentially cutting it to memory each time.  Also, define ws1, so `dim ws1 as excel.worksheet` and `dim ws2 as excel.worksheet`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a `For Loop` first of all, and then checking if the cell values match something like:

```
For i = 2 to lastRow
If Cell(i, columnNumber).value = Cell(i, columnNumber).Value Then
  //Do Something
```